# Check if files exist in a FTP remote directory outside our domain

Tags: powershell, file, authentication, ftp, remote-access

We have been asked to check if files exists in a SFTP remote directory, on a server outside our organisation, and send an email if it does exist.

I have the IP address, an account, and a password.

I found this powershell script https://www.tech2tech.fr/powershell-surveiller-des-fichiers-avec-envoi-de-mail/ , but... How can i make it work on a remote directory, using credential to access it?

I also try using ftp command, but can't find a way to check if many files exist, and not only one.

Does anyone have a solution or a way to help me?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your referenced web site contains non-English what might exclude some girls that might help on StackOverflow. Further the script doesn't shows what **you** want to try with SFTP, the script uses no FTP at all. Please show what you want and what you have done so far. Please don't expect that we write your code.

Comment: I didn't show what I had done so far, because I did'nt have a clue how to start. The module Posh-SSH greatly help, didn't know there was such thing. I posted the link because I did'nt want to post a code I didn't write. I did'nt expect to have such a help, juste hoped for some... hint, or lead... But thank you for your coment

Answer (score 0):

You need to start from here:

```
$cred = Get-StoredCredential -Target creds;
$SFTPSession = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName sftp.server.org -Credential $cred
Test-SFTPPath $SFTPSession "/path/filename.txt"  # check if file exist
Remove-SFTPSession -SessionID 0 -Verbose
Get-SFTPSession #  ensure the session is closed
```

Than you can add a condition and send mail:

```
Send-MailMessage -To “<recipient’s email>” -From “<sender’s email>”  -Subject 
“message subject” -Body “Some text!” -Credential (Get-Credential) -SmtpServer 
“<smtp server>” -Port 587
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Posh-SSH module.
You can store your password as a plain string in your script, but it would be better to use Import-Clixml to securely store credentials.
Check out online documentation of both modules.

```
# Install and import module

Install-Module Posh-SSH
Import-Module Posh-SSH
$host = <sftp-location>
$port = <port>

#Set Credentials
$user = <username>
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString <password> -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $pass)
$path = <location to check>

# Initiate SFTP session
$session = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName $host -Credential $Credential -Port $port -AcceptKey:$true
# Check if files exist on specified location
Test-SFTPPath -SFTPSession $session -Path $path

# Check if more than one file
$items = Get-SFTPChildItem -SFTPSession $session -Path $path

if($items -gt 1) {

   <your code>
} 

# close session
Remove-SFTPSession -SFTPSession $session
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
I don't understand the meaning of this part:
Test-SFTPPath -SFTPSession $session -Path $path

Is it really necessary? The part under "#Check if more than on file" do the job, right?

Comment: @Matt Yess, you can leave out Test-SFTPPath. It is simply another method to check whether there are any files on the location and returns a **boolean**. Get-SFTPChildItem returns all the **files** on the specified location, which is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all !

With your help I was able to complete the task.

Here is what I used:

```
Install and import module
Install-Module Posh-SSH
Import-Module Posh-SSH
$SFTPhost = "My_SFTP_Server"
$port = "22"

#Set Credentials
    $user = "test_sftp"
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "******" -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $pass
    $path = "/Prod/saved"
    
    # Initiate SFTP session
    $session = New-SFTPSession -ComputerName $SFTPhost -Credential $Credential -Port $port -AcceptKey:$true
    # Check if files exist on specified location
    Test-SFTPPath -SFTPSession $session -Path $path
    
    
    # Check if more than one file
    $items = (Get-SFTPChildItem -SFTPSession $session -Path $path | measure-object).count
    
    
    if($items_path -gt 1) {
    
    
    Send-MailMessage -To 'toto <toto@MyDomain.com>' -From 'No Reply Check <no_reply_CheckFiles@MyDomain.com>'  -Subject 'Files on server' -Body 'There is files in PROD repertory'  -SmtpServer “My_SMTP_server_Address”
       
    } 
    
    # close session
    Remove-SFTPSession -SFTPSession $session
```